# What causes php ext-grpc to report 'failed to connect' error during k8s grpc server redeployment?

Tags: php, grpc

Call chain:

php server ---> kube-proxy ----> golang grpc server pods

Version:

- php: 7.4
- php ext-grpc: 1.54.0
- golang: 1.20
- golang-grpc: 1.54.0

The problem that arises:

When my `grpc server pod` is redeployed, the PHP client will report an error:

e.g. 1:

code:14,message: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:<ServiceIP:PORT>: Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused

e.g. 2:

code:14,message: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:<ServiceIP:PORT>: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown

e.g. 3:

code:14, message: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:<ServiceIP:PORT>: tcp handshaker shutdown.

Then after the deployment is complete, the error disappears. During this period, there will be tens of seconds of service unavailability.

How can I fix this problem in php code, or ext-grpc extension code, or avoid it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.